# WordPress does not allow me to upload a .xml file

Tags: plugins, uploads, import

What's a good plugin to upload a .xml file?
here is the final question for now.. under

Tools: / Import: / WordPress  i get this message:

> Howdy! Upload your WordPress eXtended
>   RSS (WXR) file and we’ll import the
>   posts, pages, comments, custom fields,
>   categories, and tags into this site.
>
> Choose a WXR file to upload, then
>   click Upload file and import.

Any ideas what i need?

sincerely

Jim

Answer (score 1):

You need an export from another WordPress blog. That's what the import tool is for.

If you're trying to import from another blog format to WordPress, [look at this list of possibilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content).

Comment: Delicious XML Importer was installed, but still giving me issues uploading the external pages wp

Comment: I get this error: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/2011/03.  and there is no such folder